# SQL How to combine two triggers in one Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

I have a assigment where I have to make a trigger that fires when I insert on two tables: review and props.

The tables are
PROPS (title, director, club, member, prop_date, slogan)
REVIEWS (club, nick, msg_date, title, director, subject, msg)

Basically, the triggers make that when I insert a new row it checks if there is another one with the date (in props-> prop_date and in reviews-> msg_date) then if there is a match, it increases the new row date by 1 day.

Here's what I have done that works well in two triggers separately. Can it be combined in a just one trigger? My database is Oracle11G

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_review
BEFORE INSERT ON review
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE datetime1 DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT msg_date INTO datetime1 FROM review WHERE msg_date = :NEW.msg_date; 
    :NEW.msg_date := SYSDATE+1;
END t_review;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_props
BEFORE INSERT ON props
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE datetime1 DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT prop_date INTO datetime1 FROM props WHERE prop_date = :NEW.prop_date;
    :NEW.prop_date := SYSDATE+1;
END t_props;
/
```

Comment: You cannot combine them in a single trigger. You might be able to refactor parts of it for better re-use (although the gain is negligible in your case). Why would you want to do it?

Comment: You cannot. You need to have one trigger per table. Also, your code will throw **no data found error** whenever prop_date doesn't match with the new date. Also, if prop_date and new_date has time portion, then they might never match.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted because the exercise doesn't explain well and I had understood that it must be only one trigger.

Comment: You're changing it to tomorrow's date, not increasing the original date by a day. You're also risking mutating-table errors, and this won't handle concurrent sessions both inserting the same date at the same time. And what is supposed to happen if you get a third insert for the same original date; you'll then get two for day+1? Seems like an odd assignment.